# What is the regex syntax for a file name with spaces

Tags: regex, syntax

I'm using a custom blog syndication tool and having problems in using the regex syntax.

Example:

The original code

```
<img src="http://www.mydomain.com/some image.png">
```

I tried:

```
/\<img src\=\"http\:\/\/www\.mydomain\.com\/some\%20image\.png\"\>/
```

and

```
/\<img src\=\"http\:\/\/www\.mydomain\.com\/some image\.png\"\>/
```

But none of them seem to work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want to capture src value or something else?

Comment: Where is the regex syntax documented?  It could have any number of regex engines and syntaxes which would affect this.  By custom, do you mean that you wrote it?

Comment: The plugin that I use has a field called regex replacements. When I make any changes to the regex section, the resulting output is reflected. For example, I managed to replace a URL using regex, but unable to manipulate an image file with 'spaces' The regex works fine if there are no spaces in the image file.. just stumped on how to get the regex to work when there are spaces. Obviously the %20 doesn't seem to work in this aspect.

Comment: @Sledge81 Just out of curiosity have you tried using this ? &nbsp; Just a long shot :)

Comment: Please identify the plugin, and if possible, identify the flavor of regex it expects -- e.g., BRE, ERE, PCRE.

Comment: @FailedDev Thanks for the suggestion, but didn't quite help.
@others let me rephrase.. if you had to use a regex to identify or replace a file name with spaces, how would it be done? ex: my file.pdf I would assume that if it was myfile.pdf then the regex would be `/myfile\.pdf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern delimiters (/) at either end mean the regex engine should know where the pattern ends, so the engine shouldn't be confused by a space. Are you sure there isn't something else wrong with the pattern? I suspect this is the most likely problem.

You might like to try the %20 without the % being escaped.

Another thing to try could be an escaped space (with a preceding backslash).

Otherwise, you could try using \s to match a space - it's reasonably standard in regex engines (but also matches tabs, line feeds and carriage returns).